# Relative path of excel files, python

Tags: python, path, pycharm

I am trying to access an Excel file in Python, but I'm getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input/sales-feb-2014.xlsx'
```

Could you please help me defining the path of the file?

Python Code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook    
sheet = open_workbook('input/sales-feb-2014.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)    
print (sheet.cell_value(3,0))
```

[image: The screenshoot shows the content of my directory:]

Comment: It's probably at `$PATH` issue, go to PyCharm settings and make sure `merge1Rai` folder is in the PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to add the full path to `open_workbook(your_full_path_comes_here)` or change the directory you are working in before.

You can use the `os`module to before calling your variable.

```
import os

os.chdir(r'...your/path/input')
```